# Pagination gives extra page with no results

Tags: loop, pagination

I'm trying to implement pagination on a category page. The pagination is working, but now for some reason the pagination plugin I'm using is noting one extra page of results, when that page is actually empty.

I'm pretty sure it doesn't have anything to do with the pagination plugin because I've seen reports of people having the same problem with next_posts_link and previous_posts_link.

Anybody have any idea how this could happen?

Loop:

```
<?php       
global $myOffset;
$myOffset = 11;
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('offset='.$myOffset.'&cat=6&posts_per_page=12'.'&paged='.$paged);
?>

<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

STUFF

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {
   // get yo paginate on
   wp_paginate();
} ?>
```

Edit:
I am also using this functions.php plugin to enable the offset parameter in a custom wp_query:

```
function my_post_limit($limit) {
    global $paged, $myOffset;
    if (empty($paged)) {
            $paged = 1;
    }
    $postperpage = intval(get_option('posts_per_page'));
    $pgstrt = ((intval($paged) -1) * $postperpage) + $myOffset . ', ';
    $limit = 'LIMIT '.$pgstrt.$postperpage;
    return $limit;
} //end function my_post_limit
```

Comment: Are you able to try another pagination plugin just incase its that plugin not obeying the offset? Have you tried http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/ I swear by it but never needed to use it with an offset so I cannot say this will fix your issue but worth a try...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure, but I have a guess that it is because you are using pagination and `offset` at the same time. Pagination might be calculated for whole set, but you are reducing set size with offset so number of pages becomes overestimated.

Comment: You are right, that's it! When offset is 0, every paginated page has contents (no empty pages). Now of course the tough question, is there any way around this?

I'm using this function in conjunction with a filter to enable offset in a custom wp_query and still have pagination:

`function my_post_limit($limit) {
 global $paged, $myOffset;
 if (empty($paged)) {
   $paged = 1;
 }
 $postperpage = intval(get_option('posts_per_page'));
 $pgstrt = ((intval($paged) -1) * $postperpage) + $myOffset . ', ';
 $limit = 'LIMIT '.$pgstrt.$postperpage;
 return $limit;
} //end function my_post_limit`

Comment: @Squrler sorry, I hadn't worked with pagination enough to have a good idea how to work around it. I'll update if I think of something. btw please add this code snippet to original question so it's easier to read.

Comment: +1 - to moving the code into the question.. (code blocks are horrible to read in comments).

Comment: Will do that. As an aside (and please, I'm sorry if I should not ask this here), is it possible to add code blocks in a comment?

Comment: @Squrler not sure what you mean. You can add code to comments (as you did), but you can't indent it and such, comments are not really meant for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the more native `get_adjacent_posts()` function to see if the problem is the `next_posts_link()` function. For additional information i wrote an [educational plugin](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Easy-Pagination-Deamon) that's well documented/commented to giude you through the process.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I'm not sure I understand what you mean with 'the more native function'. Isn't next_posts_link also a native function? In addition, I'm using the wp_paginate function and not the next_posts_link function.

Comment: @Squrler - there are a some functions inside wordpress that offer a layer above other functions. So `next_posts_link()` is just a simplified version of `get_adjacent_posts()`. There are many others like that. Another example `has_post_format()` is a layer above `is_object_in_term()`. Just take a look at the plugin code and read through the inline-comments and you'll understand better.